# systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

My /var/log/syslog and dmesg is being filled with errors from systemd. Searching the internet for: systemd-journald "operation not supported", gives no valuable results.

Here is a sample of my syslog

```
Jul 16 03:03:20 gaming kernel: [12187.062877] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:20 gaming kernel: [12187.072868] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:20 gaming kernel: [12187.310756] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:20 gaming kernel: [12187.321562] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:20 gaming kernel: [12187.332766] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:20 gaming kernel: [12187.342772] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:23 gaming systemd[1]: Started Session c1192 of user pinker.
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.020723] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.030607] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.129098] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.138991] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.303171] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.313662] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.324551] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.334600] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.434910] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
Jul 16 03:03:24 gaming kernel: [12191.444927] systemd-journald[356]: Failed to open system journal: Operation not supported
```

OS: Ubuntu 18.04 using Overlayfs root. I've been running this setup for years without problem.

I'm not sure what other information to provide.

Edit:

/etc/fstab

```
/media/root-ro/ / overlay lowerdir=/media/root-ro/,upperdir=/media/root-rw/overlay/,workdir=/media/root-rw/overlay-workdir/_ 0 1
UUID=42f127b6-22b4-414d-a70f-b7c3d2153310 /home ext4 errors=remount-ro 0 2
```

My raid1 is mounted later by a script within a chroot Debian system (chroot, not systemd-spawn).

```
mount -t btrfs -o noatime,nodiratime LABEL=raid1 /mnt/4
```

Comment: It seems like systemd-journald is trying to log to a read-only location. Please post your /etc/systemd/journald.conf if you've modified it, and also post the output of `lsattr -R /var/log/journal/`.

Comment: Oh and also post your /etc/fstab

Comment: /etc/systemd/journald was never changed. It only has one uncommented line `[Journal]`. Everything under /var/log/journal/ are `--------------e---`

Comment: If you never mount the btrfs filesystem, do you still see the same errors?

Comment: Yes, I'm still getting the errors, in syslog and dmesg. (I'm embarrassed I didn't think to check that before)

Comment: Probably unrelated, but you could try what people suggest in [this thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/799841/systemd-journald-doesnt-start-at-all)

Comment: Did you try what was suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can take several actions to diagnose the problem.
As per [the relevant man page](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/systemd-journald.service.8.html),

> The journal service stores log data either persistently below `/var/log/journal` or in a volatile way below `/run/log/journal/` (in the latter case it is lost at reboot). By default, log data is stored persistently if `/var/log/journal/` exists during boot, with an implicit fallback to volatile storage otherwise. Use `Storage=` in `journald.conf(5)` to configure where log data is placed, independently of the existence of `/var/log/journal/`.
>
> On systems where `/var/log/journal/` does not exist yet but where persistent logging is desired (and the default `journald.conf` is used), it is sufficient to create the directory, and ensure it has the correct access modes and ownership:
>
> ```
> mkdir -p /var/log/journal
> systemd-tmpfiles --create --prefix /var/log/journal
> ```
>
> See `journald.conf(5)` for information about the configuration of this
> service.

Please post the output of the following commands to see where are logs written, and if the daemon stopped uncleanly

```
$ ls -dl /var/log/journal/
$ ls -alR /var/log/journal/
$ ls -dl /run/log/journal/
$ ls -alR /run/log/journal/
$ cat /etc/systemd/journald.conf
$ journalctl --list-boots
```

Check integrity of logs

```
$ journalctl --verify
```

If anything shows corrupted, we may follow up.

If you are adventurous, try removing `/var/log/journal/*/system.journal` and restarting the service.
It doesn't harm, but you will lose the log.
I don't think that will solve the problem, but you may try.

**Sources**

1. https://www.loggly.com/ultimate-guide/linux-logging-with-systemd/